# IF & AND conditions not working in Google Sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, conditional-statements, google-sheets-formula, higher-order-functions

I'm not the best in excel so I would like to ask about some conditionals, I'm adding the AND to my original formula that is this one:

```
=IF(G2>=0.8, "Valid", "Not Valid")
```

Basically if my value is equal or higher to 0.8 print Valid if not "Not valid" everything fine with that but when I try to add the AND with this formula:

```
=IF(AND(G2>=0.8, G2<=0.2, "Zero"),"Valid", "Not Valid")
```

So what I'm trying to do in this formula is that if the value is lower than 0.2 print "Zero", any value between 0.2 to 0.8 will be not valid and everything higher than 0.8 is valid so. I'm not really sure what is missing. This is an image from my sheet:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delete everything in E2:E and use this in E2:

```
=INDEX(IF((G2:G< 0.2)*(G2:G<>""), "Zero", 
       IF((G2:G>=0.2)*(G2:G<=0.8), "Not Valid",
       IF(G2:G>0.8, "Valid", )))
```

or try:

```
=INDEX(IF(G2:G="",,IFERROR(VLOOKUP(G2:G, 
 {0, "Zero"; 0.2, "Not Valid"; 0.8, "Valid"}, 2, 1)))
```